# Dynamic background image with background color

Tags: html, css

I am currently having an issue with background color and background images. The project i am working on must use both a color and a background image. For example the image will fill up half of a div and the color will fill up the other half.

Now normally to do this i would use the following piece of CSS:

```
background: blue url('img.png) right no-repeat;
```

and this works perfectly but on this project in particular the user can set the background image themselves using a CMS system. So to apply the background images i am using an inline style on each of the divs then the div has its own color in an external stylesheet like so.

**stylesheet.css**

```
.bg-color {
    background: blue;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="bg-color" style="background:url('img.png') right no-repeat;">

</div>
```

Now when doing this the background image overrides everything, is there a way for me to achieve the results i am looking for dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: use `background-color` for `.bg-color` and `background-image` for inline style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default value of the background shorthand you have on `style=` is `transparent` and that is overwriting the color you give in the class `bg-color`. try:

```
.bg-color {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS try using:

```
.bg-color {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

instead of only `background: blue;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [solution](http://codepen.io/qtgye/pen/gGKBJ)

You may use shorthand notation to incorporate both backgrounds.

```
<div style="background: url(http://scienceblogs.com/gregladen/files/2012/12/Beautifull-cat-cats-14749885-1600-1200.jpg) no-repeat, green;
 background-size: 50%;"></div>
```